# How do I write a URL where a folder does not exist, which will not make me change page

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, folderbrowserdialog

I want write an URL like this

http://my-site.it/Existingfolder/FolderNotExist

But I would that url will remain the same (with FolderNotExist) but continue to show this page

http://my-site.it/Existingfolder/

How can i do using .httaccess ?

Actually my Website in Joomla go to Error404 with 
http://my-site.it/Existingfolder/FolderNotExist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule **before default Joomla** front controller rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/[^/]+/?$ $1/ [L]
```